# how to make the program ask the user for a input for length and use the input to make the password as long as the user would like

Tags: python, function, variables, user-input, password-generator

```
#random password generator
import random
unified_code = "awertyuiosqpdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+"

passlength1=input("how long should your password be")
pass_length2=input("how long should your password be")

def generatrandompaassword():
    length = random.randint(passlength1,pass_length2 )

    password = "" 

    for index in range(length):
        randomCharacter = random.choice(unified_code)
        password = password + randomCharacter



    return password

passworder = generatrandompaassword()
print(passworder)
print("This is your new password")
```

this won't let me post for some reason what is a comment

*this is the code iv made I started python a couple of days ago so I'm pretty new to it*

fist I tried putting one-variable and than asking the user for the input and inserting the input into the program and using that to find the length of how long the password should be can get help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code - Your code needed minor changes

```py
# random password generator
import random
unified_code = "awertyuiosqpdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+"

pass_length1 = int(input("What should be the min length your password be: "))
pass_length2 = int(input("What should be the max length your password be: "))

def generatrandompaassword():
    length = random.randint(pass_length1, pass_length2 )
    password = "" 
    for index in range(length):
        randomCharacter = random.choice(unified_code)
        password = password + randomCharacter
    return password

passworder = generatrandompaassword()
print(passworder)
print("This is your new password")
```

The input your receive from the user is of type `str`, so you need to convert it into `int` data type.

Output

```sh
What should be the min length your password be: 5
What should be the max length your password be: 15
vyA7ROviA
This is your new password
```

Suggestions:

- stick to either using `_` or camelCasing. `pass_length1` and `randomCharacter`  are of two styles.
- try to keep your functions names easy to understand. use `generate_random_password` than `generatrandompaassword`
- Give some space to `=` before and after.

> Read a bit about python PEP standards to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote your code.
You can read the comments to see what is happening.
Essentially, we have a list of characters that will be used in the password.
We then ask the user for the length of their password, and convert it to a number.
After, we loop through the length and add a random character to the password.

```
import random
characters = "awertyuiosqpdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+"

# Get the length of the password, and cast it to an integer so it can be used in the for loop ahead
length = int(input("how long should your password be? "))

def generatrandompaassword():
    password = ""

    # For every character in the password, get a random character and add that to the password
    for i in range(length):
        password += random.choice(characters)

    return password

# Get the password
password = generatrandompaassword()
print("This is your new password: " + password)
```